# Find command inconsistent output , wild card not working correctly

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find

I am using find command to create a list of files that I want to use for distribution bundle. but find is not able to get the list of all files

Below is my directory structure

```
.
├── 1.cpp
├── test
│   └── 1.cpp
└── test1
├── 1.cpp
└── test11
    ├── 1.h
    └── 2.cpp
```

below is the command and  its output **( note: it does not bring the ./test1/test11/2.cpp)**

```
$ find . -name *.cpp
./test/1.cpp
./1.cpp
./test1/1.cpp
```

however when i am using the specific name it is able to locate the file

```
$ find . -name 2.cpp
./test1/test11/2.cpp
```

Comment: Can you try this find . -name "*.cpp"

Comment: that worked thanks. please add an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because `*.cpp` is expanded to `1.cpp` because there is a match in current directory use quotes `"*.cpp"` or escape star `\*.cpp` to avoid expansion and pass star literaly as argument for find.

Answer (score 1):

Add double quote in your search string `find . -name "*.cpp"`